# Getting Private File from AWS S3 with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to get private file from AWS S3 But getting error

```
 $client = S3Client::factory([
        'version' => 'latest',
        'region'  => 'us-west-2',
        'signature'    => 'v4',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => '****',
            'secret' => '-****'
        ]
    ]);


  $bucket =  'name';
    $file = 'lks/002geH1P1WFXGHWafCwgTw5mwm58X.pdf';
    $url = "{$bucket}/{$file}";

    $request = $client->get($url);
    $signedUrl = $client->createPresignedUrl($request, '+10 minutes');
    echo  $signedUrl;
```

I am getting this error

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, string given,
>   called in /home/ubuntu/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClientTrait.php
>   on line 78 and defined in
>   /home/ubuntu/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php on line 202

Answer (score 1):

This works ... Hope it will help others ;)

```
$cmd = $client->getCommand('GetObject', [
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $file
        ]);

        $request = $client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+20 minutes');
        $presignedUrl = (string)$request->getUri();
        echo $presignedUrl;
```